# GTID replication from a MySQL 5.7.38 Master to MariDB 10.6.10?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, gtid

Is it possible to use GTID in a replication scenario where MySQL 5.7.38 is the master and MariaDB 10.6.10 is the slave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB claims it should "just work".

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-replication/#replicating-from-mysql-master-to-mariadb-slave

> Replication from MySQL 5.6 with GTID, `binlog_rows_query_log_events` and ignorable events works starting from MariaDB 10.0.22 and MariaDB 10.1.8. In this case MariaDB will remove the MySQL GTIDs and other unneeded events and instead adds its own GTIDs.

However, I don't know what would happen if you use a data type in the MySQL source that is not supported in MariaDB. For example, the native JSON type, or the updated datetime format. If you avoid features that are incompatible between the two products, it *might* work.

I don't use MariaDB, so I will not test this.

You should stop thinking of MariaDB as compatible with MySQL. MariaDB forked in 2010, and both products have been changing gradually since then. There are now lots of features implemented in both products that are incompatible with the other. They are effectively different products.

Comment: The [type_mysql_json](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_json/) plugin will handle the JSON data type (but not MySQL json syntax). "updated datetime" is one I missed. Totally agree with test it well.